# How to clean up a socket after connection failure?

Tags: c++, sockets

The code is offered below. I create a TCP socket and try to connect. The connection fails. However, something is left in the buffer and the socket remains readable. Is there way to clean up the socket in this case? Thank you very much for the help.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct sockaddr_in sai;
    sai.sin_family = AF_INET;
    int rv = inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.10.131.1", &(sai.sin_addr));
    sai.sin_port = htons(1234);

    int r = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sai), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (r < 0)
    {
        printf("connection failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }


    fd_set r_set;
    FD_ZERO(&r_set);
    FD_SET(sock, &r_set);

    int n = select(sock + 1, &r_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (n > 0)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(sock, &r_set))
        {
            printf("socket %d is readable\n", sock);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Execution result:

```
connection failed: Connection refused
socket 3 is readable
```

Comment: To determine if the socket actually has data available call `ioctl(socket,FIONREAD,&bytes_available)`.

Comment: The only thing you have to clean up is the socket. Close it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Pointless. There won't be any data. Where could it have come from?

Comment: You should also check whether `socket` itself failed. You need to be ultra paranoid when using sockets. Every call to a function that can fail should be checked for failure. `socket()` is one of those functions that can fail. You assumed success.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in the buffer. Being "readable" means you had some event on the socket, which at this point you already know - connection attempt failed. There's really no point in using `select(2)` here and no need to cleanup anything.

Comment: To be more precise, as far as `select()` is concerned, a socket (or any file descriptor, for that matter) is "readable" if a call to `read()` would not block, or would fail with EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK. This happens under two circumstances: there is data to read, or the socket has been closed (in which case `read()` returns 0 without blocking). It's the second case that applies here.